# For loop for every object Jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to compare two attributes on every object. This is the code i use for this problem:

`(.result[].downlaodable or .result[].playable)` but this time jq does cartesian product. If i have 3 object, jq turns me 9 object.

I have to convert it to something like this:
`(.result[1].downlaodable or .result[1].playable)`
`(.result[2].downlaodable or .result[2].playable)`
`(.result[3].downlaodable or .result[3].playable)`

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your filter to generate the results once.

```
.result[] | .downloadable or .playable
```